# Remove spaces in a python List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to remove all the spaces in the words list.

```
words = ['', 'int', '', 'main', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'return', '0', '']
for i in words:
    words.remove('')
print(words)
```

but this prints

```
['int', 'main', '', 'return', '0', '']
```

I want `['int', 'main', 'return', '0']` as the out put.

I am using Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
words = ['', 'int', '', 'main', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'return', '0', '']
while '' in words:
    words.remove('')
print(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list comprehension:

```
[word for word in words if word != '']
```